# Deploying to Heroku: Dynamic Env variables are undefined

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, environment-variables

I have an Express.js application with a `/CreateShipment` endpoint that takes in JSON data to create a specific shipment for a client's order. The issue I am running into is the clients have different account credentials that we want to use. So I created a class to initialise the Axios instance for each individual request, based on the client name so that the authorization headers passed matched those of the client's keys.

**courierProvider.js**

```js
const axios = require("axios").default
require("dotenv").config()
const { hashifyClient } = require('../utils/hashify-client')

class Post {
  constructor(clientName) {
    const clientHash = hashifyClient(clientName)
    this.clientNumber = clientHash
  }

  getHeaders() {
    return {
      "Account-Number": process.env[`${this.clientNumber}_ACC_NUMBER`] || process.env.ACC_NUMBER,
      "Authorization": process.env[`${this.clientNumber}_AUTH`] || process.env.AUTH,
    }
  }

  postBase() {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://api.shippingendpoint.com/shipping/v1/',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        ...this.getHeaders()
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The code above is my class I use to setup the Axios instance for each request depending on the client name.

When I test this in my local setup with NodeJS with different client names, the environment variables in the headers change and everything is all good. But when I run this in Heroku and I log the values, they are returned as `undefined` and it defaults to my fallback variables.

The code that calls this is a POST endpoint `CreateShipment`.

**courier.js**

```js
const { Post } = require('../endpoints/courierProvider')

router.post("/CreateShipment", apiAuth, async (req, res) => {
        let AP_Shipment_Body = AP_Shipment_Cx(req.body)
        let post = new Post(clientName);
        let postBase = post.postBase()
        
        let results = await postBase.post('shipments', AP_Shipment_Body)
})
```

Now when this class is initialised and the request made, it is being made to my fallback account instead of the client's account. Yes, the config variable is set inside Heroku.

I can't for the life of me figure out why in Heroku it says the env vars are `undefined` when passed with a client that has shipping credentials in the environment, and when testing in my local I run into no issues.

I have tried checking the environment variables multiple times both through Heroku CLI tool and their GUI, each time the variables are there. Logging the resulting dynamic environment variable, reloading the dyno and more. None of which change the outcome of my results.

I was expecting to have the headers change when a client that does have saved variables in our environment to be used in the request instead of the fallback variables.

Comment: Client-side code runs in your users' web browser, not on your server. It has no access to the server environment, and therefore no access to its environment variables. (It appears to work locally since you're running your front-end code on your development server, but that doesn't work in general.)

Comment: If you need access to environment variables client-side, it's common to bake them into your production code at build time. But in this case that will leak _all_ of your clients' account numbers and auth tokens to all of your other clients—that's a huge problem. You either need to handle this on the _server_ or have each client provide their own credentials.

Comment: I appreciate your response but this whole thing is server side, I am not trying to access environment variables from the client. It is all server side. Please note I am not new to JS and I am running into a road block with Heroku based hosting. I am using saved client credentials in the environment, client, as in commercial customers who do not interact with this. The pain point is the OR (||) in courierProvier.js where it chooses which credentials to input into the headers. The clients credentials exist in the env, but when ran returns `undefined` (only in Heroku).

Comment: In that case, are you sure `this.clientNumber` is being set correctly? What is `hashifyClient`, and is it returning what you expect it to return?

Comment: Yeah, `this.clientNumber` is being set correctly and is accessible, like I stated above, when I test on my local machine everything works as designed, but when running on Heroku there seems to be something different about it. I am hoping someone else has previously ran into this issue with Heroku environment variables. `hashifyClient` is just a string encryption to hash and then returns a slice of 10 char length.

Comment: "Yeah, `this.clientNumber` is being set correctly and is accessible"—you're asserting that everything is correct, but something must be wrong. Let's ignore your local copy, that's not really relevant. Log or print `this.clientNumber`, `\`${this.clientNumber}_ACC_NUMBER\``, and `process.env[\`${this.clientNumber}_ACC_NUMBER\`]` on Heroku. Run `heroku config:get SOME_CLIENT_NUMBER_ACC_NUMBER`. Make sure there aren't any errant newlines. Make sure you're looking at the correct app and not a staging app or something. Finally, how did you set the environment variables?